# exact target import activity file size limit

Tags: marketing-cloud, automation, import

I have an import activity in exact target. I specify import activity to look for files with some pattern. My question is, what is the limit on file size of an import activity?

Thanks.

Comment: I've done imports of close to half a gigabyte with no problems.  Is there a specific problem or error you're getting?

Comment: no its a general question. So, the answer is there are no limits right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No limits. *

*Keep in mind it could take a very long time for large files and if it becomes a huge processor bottleneck then one of the DBA's may kill the process.  As we say, trust, but verify.  I do know of at least one case where some limits were reached; the customer sent ET the hardware with the data so we could load it for them, but that was for IMMENSE amounts of data, stuff that made my 500Mb imports seem tiny.

Answer (score 0):

I've actually just been through through this for a client where we had to import 17+ million records. It depends on the kind of import -- overwrite (to an empty DE or list) or an Add/Update. If you're doing the Import to a DE you're probably going to be ok depending on the actual amount of data. If you're importing to a List, and especially if you're doing and Add/Update, you'll need to keep each import to under 500,000 records.